# Demerge the merged cell in XSLT

Tags: xslt

Can someone help me with the below xslt question.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <catalog>
<cd>
    <title rowmerge="f">Title 1</title>
    <artist rowmerge="f">sample 1</artist>
    <price rowmerge="T">1</price>
    <year >1985</year>
</cd>
<cd>
    <title rowmerge="F">Title 2</title>
    <artist rowmerge="F">Sample 2</artist>
    <price rowmerge="T"></price>
    <year>1988</year>
</cd>
<cd>
    <title rowmerge="F">Title 3</title>
    <artist rowmerge="F">Sample 3</artist>
    <price rowmerge="F">3</price>
    <year>1988</year>
</cd>
<cd>
    <title rowmerge="T">Title 4</title>
    <artist rowmerge="F">sample 4</artist>
    <price rowmerge="T">4</price>
    <year >1985</year>
</cd>
<cd>
    <title rowmerge="T"></title>
    <artist rowmerge="F">Sample 5</artist>
    <price rowmerge="T"></price>
    <year>1988</year>
</cd>
</catalog>
```

Expected output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<catalog>
<cd>
    <title rowmerge="f">Title 1</title>
    <artist rowmerge="f">sample 1</artist>
    <price rowmerge="f">1</price>
    <year >1985</year>
</cd>
<cd>
    <title rowmerge="F">Title 2</title>
    <artist rowmerge="F">Sample 2</artist>
    <price rowmerge="f">1</price>
    <year>1988</year>
</cd>
<cd>
    <title rowmerge="F">Title 3</title>
    <artist rowmerge="F">Sample 3</artist>
    <price rowmerge="F">3</price>
    <year>1988</year>
</cd>
<cd>
    <title rowmerge="F">Title 4</title>
    <artist rowmerge="F">sample 4</artist>
    <price rowmerge="F">4</price>
    <year >1985</year>
</cd>
<cd>
    <title rowmerge="F">Title 4</title>
    <artist rowmerge="F">Sample 5</artist>
    <price rowmerge="F">4</price>
    <year>1988</year>
</cd>
</catalog>
```

If rowmerge  attribute is 'T' in the first cd for any tag (title/artist/price)then I need to copy the price value from first cd to next cd.  I am new to xslt.

Comment: Copy from the absolute first `cd` or from the preceeding `cd` element?

Comment: Have you tried something? Please post your try with the expected output.

Comment: I am new to xslt from today only i am seeing the xslt code.So if possile elabrate.Also this not only two cd's available.There are many CD's follwed by this.But based on Mergedtrue and null value in price we need to copy

Comment: Can you amend your question to show 3 or 4 more CDs (some with empty tags, some without), and also the output you would expect to see generated for that XML. Thank you!

Comment: Thanks for all your response.I have updated my question

Comment: In your expected output, is the 'sample 5' correct ? I mean, the previous <cd> got the 'T' rowMerge but no value copied in the expected output. Second point, your attribute value are changed in the output, is this what you expect ?

Comment: Eric updated the sample out put. Also for the second question yes we need to update.Thanks a million

Comment: Also one more thing. the tag name will be diffrent ie) it may not be CD / title / artist.It may be anything. Just a info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You first should read up on the [XSLT Identity Template](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_transform), which on its own will copy nodes from the source document to the output.

```
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

What this means is that you only need to write templates for the nodes you wish to transform. Considering just the `price` elements for now, you are trying to amend `price` elements which have a `rowmerge` set to "T" and which are empty. In this case, you want to copy the `price` from the first most preceding 'cd'. This is achieved like so:

```
<xsl:template match="price[@rowmerge='T'][not(normalize-space())]">
    <price>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="../preceding-sibling::*[1]/price" />
    </price>
</xsl:template>
```

So, it is very similar to the identity template, but it has the extra `xsl:value-of` statement to copy the value from the preceding node. Or rather the `price` value from the preceding node of the parent `cd` element.

Of course, you could repeat this template for each of the possible child elements of `cd`, but this would be a lot of repetitive coding. Better would be to have a more generic template to cover all cases:

```
<xsl:template match="*[@rowmerge='T'][not(normalize-space())]">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="../preceding-sibling::*[1]/*[name() = name(current())]" />
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:template match="*[@rowmerge='T'][not(normalize-space())]">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="../preceding-sibling::*[1]/*[name() = name(current())]" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>


    <xsl:template match="@rowmerge[. = 'T']">
        <xsl:attribute name="rowmerge">F</xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Do note there is also a template to convert the `rowmerge` attributes from having a value of `T` to `F`.

EDIT: In answer to your comment, if you have to look more than one sibling back (that is to say, you have two consecutive elements that are empty), then try one of these two expressions

```
<xsl:value-of select="../preceding-sibling::*[*[name() = name(current())][normalize-space()]][1]/*[name() = name(current())]" />

<xsl:value-of select="(../preceding-sibling::*/*[name() = name(current())][normalize-space()])[last()]" />
```

EDIT 2: If the nodes contain more than just text, then to copy all the child elements, you use `xsl:copy-of` instead of `xsl:value-of`. For example...

```
<xsl:copy-of select="../preceding-sibling::*[1]/*[name() = name(current())]/node()" />
```

Note the use of `node()` on the end, to ensure only the child nodes are copied, not the `price` (for example) element itself.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.It works well.But there is change that util the child found rowmerge to T( n number of child) and value is empty it should copy the content from original.Once it reached to rowmerge is F or rowmerge is T and content is not null then we should stop that and then if F then we dont need to copy.If we found rowmerge is T and not null Value then we need to pick the value for next row. Please help me out in this.

Comment: I have made an edit to my answer, which I think may achieve this. If it doesn't, then maybe you need to ask a whole new separate question with this new requirement. If you do, remember to show a representative sample of input XML and output XML, and any XSLT you have tried. Thanks!

Comment: thanks for your response.Its working perfectly fine.But in realtime scnerio we have tag inside a price tag. we need to check the empty value condition for that tag. ie)<cd>
    <title rowmerge="F">Title 2</title>
    <artist rowmerge="F">Sample 2</artist>
    <price rowmerge="f"><para att1="p">1</para></price>
    <year>1988</year>
</cd>  We need to copy full content with attribute

Comment: You can use `xsl:copy-of` in this instance, instead of `xsl:value-of`. I've made a final edit to my answer to show this. For future reference, if you do need to ask any new questions on StackOverflow, it's always good to show a truly representative example of your XML. Thank you!